# Google charts - How to display data with a pie chart side by side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, google-visualization

I'm currently trying to find a way to display data related to a pie chart with the generated colors like "Color Label Value Percent" in a table or in legend field.

I'm providing the charts color, so Google decide by himself.

Here an example of what I'm looking for :

[image]

Btw, i'm using Google JSAPI to generate this svg pie chart.

Comment: From now, I just came out with the pie chart and the labels (with color).From what I can see, the best solution would be to be able to retrieve the colors from the pie chart and draw a table under my pie chart with the data.

Comment: Yes, I checked. You can't extend legends like so.